# Alexa Selected Intent is empty

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, slots

Within in my skill, I have multiple intents that have been trained.

When I use the "utterance profiler" I can see that "selected intent" is empty (n/a), while "Other Considered Intents" is populated (with the correct intent and slots).

The utterance I am using is "Aspen", which should be filled as an Amazon.US_City, however, I am getting n/a for Selected Intent.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Please share your interaction model.

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue. It works fine for all languages but English (US)